# How to increment the values in one column depending upon the dynaimic values of other column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need a help in excel.. I am importing external web data to excel. The column A values changes daily/hourly.Now A7 is 22. Next hour, A6 might become as 22 and so on..

In the column B, i need incremental number starting from 1, for each changing **number** value in Column A. Any formula will be helpful..

```
ColumnA ColumnB

na  
na  
na  
na  
na  
22      1       
na  
na  
na  
34      2   
na  
na  
na  
na  
27      3       
na  
na  
na  
0       4   
na  
na  
na  
34      5
```

Comment: What is *each changing number*? When will this happen? And most importanly, **what have you tried so far?**

Comment: Hello David, Each number column A is total week hours that was put in against a task. NA, is the employee has the task, but he didn't put any hours against it. 1,2,3 is to make use of vlookup in another sheet. Till now, i am using the filter and select the non NA values.

Comment: If you just want column B to indicate the count of non-"na" values, sequentially, see my suggestion below. There are at least two pretty simple ways to do this with formula, probably more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in cell `B2`:

`=IF(A2="na","",MAX($B$1:B1)+1)`

Or you could put this in `B1`, should give the same results:

`=IF(A2="na","",COUNTIF($A$2:A2,"<>na"))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks david. That works good for me. Will start learning excel :)

Comment: You're welcome. Do consider marking this answer as Accepted, if it works for you.  Cheers.